# Uninstall Ruby on OpenSUSE (zlib error)

Tags: ruby, rvm, opensuse

I am new to Linux and Ruby. I have been searching for an answer but to no avail.

Using OpenSUSE 11.1

I recently downloaded the latest Ruby 1.9.2 and use the method make install from the source. I did not have the zlib back then.

Now, I cannot use the command "gem -d list ruby". The error says no such file to load -- zlib. I wanted to remove Ruby and RubyGem entirely from the system.

I tried using RVM but i couldn't figure it out on how to use. Been trying to install it for ages, but it is still useless, as the "type rvm | head -n1" comes out to rvm is hashed (usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm) even though I added the "[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session" to both .bash_profile and .bashrc.

Been working on it whole night. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, installed Ruby 1.9.2 on openSUSE 11.4 using RVM.  This was a clean install of openSUSE and I was trying to get a Rails development environment set up.

To address this, I removed my 1.9.2 instance using:

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.2
```

Then, I installed zlib-devel and openssl using:

```
sudo zypper install zlib-devel openssl
```

I then had to delete the 1.9.2 source files from rvm's src folder.  This can be found under ~/.rvm/src

The source was there for ruby 1.9.2, rubygems, and yaml.  I removed all three, leaving the ~/.rvm/src/rvm folder there in case it was needed by rvm.

Lastly, I re-installed ruby 1.9.2 using:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Gems worked after that and I was able to do a gem update --system and gem install rails.

I hope this helps.  I see this is an old, outstanding issue.

Mike